# Image not showing on page template in Twenty Fifteen-theme

Tags: page-template, theme-twenty-fifteen

I'm creating a custom template for a few of my subpages using the Twenty Fifteen theme. For some reason the linked image below won't show, even though the url seems to be correct.

I've started with `page.php`, renamed it and added these three lines of code below the `#main` opening tag:

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'om-oss' ) ) : ?>
<img style="height:373px;width:83.3334%;margin:0 8.3333%;" src="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/img/bil.jpg" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

The complete code in my new template looks like this:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Ny side */ ?> 
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php if ( is_page( 'om-oss' ) ) : ?>
            <img style="height:373px;width:83.3334%;margin:0 8.3333%;" src="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/img/bil.jpg" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The image is located in:

> wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\img\bil.jpg

Changing the url up gives me a symbol of a broken link, so it seems nothing is wrong with it. Even so I'm just getting a empty box with a border around it instead of the actual image. Anyone know what might be wrong?

Edit: I'm by the way running the page locally, using WAMP.

What it looks like now:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_template_directory()` returns a system path not a resource uri.

Use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead.